# Return index with enumerate

Tags: python

I am basically trying to return the starting index of a DNA string where A and G form the majority over the next five letters.

See code

```
def a_g_majority_positions(dna):

    ### BEGIN SOLUTION
    list=[]
    for index, item in enumerate(dna):
            count=0
            x=0
            index1=index
            while count < 5:
                letter=dna[index1]
                index1+=1
                count+=1
                if letter == 'A':
                    x+=1
                elif letter == 'G':
                    x+=1
            if x>=3:
                list.append(index)
    return list




    ### END SOLUTION
a_g_majority_positions("AACCGGTTAACCGGTT")
```

I always get a string index out of range error. The correct answer for the dna at the end is [0,1,4,5,8,9]

Comment: You increment `index1` (which is based on `index` initially) five times. What happens when `index` is already equal to `len(dna) - 1`?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer... I added this:            "if (len(dna)-index)<5:
                return list" and it worked!

Comment: Why did you delete your question instead of accepting an answer?

Comment: @User973: If your problem is solved, don't remove the contents of the question, just click the check mark next to the answer that solved it to indicate the problem was solved by that answer (and reward the person who helped you).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `count` method to count the letters of interest.  Start the run of five up until you don't have enough positions left:

```
def a_g_majority_positions(dna):

    lst = []
    for start5 in range(len(dna)-4):
        five = dna[start5:start5+5]
        if five.count('A') + five.count('G') >= 3:
            lst.append(start5)
    return lst
```

Or, for the one-statement version, checking each character for being in "AG":

```
lst = [start5 for start5 in range(len(dna)-4)
       if sum(char in "AG"
              for char in dna[start5:start5+5]) >= 3]
```

Output in either case is

```
[0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to break out of the `for` loop when there are less than 5 letters left:

```
def a_g_majority_positions(dna):
    result = list()
    for index, item in enumerate(dna):
        if index + 5 >= len(dna):
            break
        count = 0
        x = 0
        while count < 5:
            letter = dna[index + count]
            count += 1
            if letter == 'A':
                x += 1
            elif letter == 'G':
                x += 1
        if x >= 3:
            result.append(index)
    return result

print(a_g_majority_positions("AACCGGTTAACCGGTT"))
```

**Output**

```
[0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9]
```

**Note**

Don't use `list` as a variable name. It's built-in class and you will introduce hard to find errors by using it as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break early from the function when index is greater than `len(dna) - 5`. Otherwise you try to access `dna[len(dna)]`, which is out of range.

```
def a_g_majority_positions(dna):

### BEGIN SOLUTION
list=[]
for index, item in enumerate(dna):
        count=0
        x=0
        index1=index
        if index > len(dna) - 5:
            break
        while count < 5:
            letter=dna[index1]
            index1+=1
            count+=1
            if letter == 'A':
                x+=1
            elif letter == 'G':
                x+=1
        if x>=3:
            list.append(index)
return list




### END SOLUTION
a_g_majority_positions("AACCGGTTAACCGGTT")

# Result [0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9]
```